# How to show full command field with sort option in ps command?

Tags: linux, shell

I am a beginner in server management.
I am monitoring the server performance with this command:

```
ps --sort -rss -eo pid,user,uid,pri,nice,vsz,rss,s,%cpu,%mem,time,comm | head -n 20
```

How can I show the full command field (not just its name) with the sort by rss enabled?

I have tried with `-f` but it returns an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `args` (or one of its aliases, `cmd` or `command`) instead of `comm`:

```
ps --sort -rss -eo pid,user,uid,pri,nice,vsz,rss,s,%cpu,%mem,time,args | head -n 20
```

See [the format specifiers](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#STANDARD_FORMAT_SPECIFIERS) for details.